# Multiple Virtual Machines with unique IPs accessible via physical network?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

How do I need to configure my network adapters in order to have multiple Virtual Machines with unique IPs that are accessible outside the host PC?

I currently have two virtual windows servers but I noticed both have the same IP. I tried setting the IP manually but then it cannot connect at all. Right now they are both set to “Bridged,” as that’s the only way I found I can access the Virtual Machines outside of the host.

Answer (score 0):

So based on some googling and even [this Stack Exchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29999/why-are-my-two-virtual-machines-getting-the-same-ip-address), I mistakenly assumed that Virtual Machines having the same IP was normal. However, while troubleshooting it occured to me that I had cloned these Virtual Machines. Indeed, they both had the same MAC. I changed one and it acquired a new IP address.

All is good now.